# xsd validation enum element required or optional (xs:schema version 1.0 )

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema, xsd-1.0

I have xsd validation file:

```
<xs:complexType name="metadata">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="app_name" type="AppDataType" minOccurs="4" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="AppDataType">
        <xs:attribute name="ERE" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="AppDataName" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="Value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="AppDataName">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="enum_1" />
        <xs:enumeration value="enum_2" />
        <xs:enumeration value="enum_3" />
        <xs:enumeration value="enum_4" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Validation works fine when app_name appear in xml less than 4 times - its ok. 
Problem is, when app_name appear 4 or more time but with "Name" value setup to eg enum_1, enum_2, enum_2, enum_2, enum_4 -> I have at least 4 app_name so validation is passed (elements can be repeated - its ok for me), but I need to have also enum_3 in app_name, basically I want to have (eg) enum_3 and enum_1 as a required(if not appear in xml then validation fails), but enum_2 and enum_4 as optional.

I tried:

```
<xs:enumeration value="enum_2" use="required"/>
```

but is incorrect as well as minOccurs="1".

I also tried:

```
    <xs:complexType name="metadata">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="app_name" type="AppDataType" minOccurs="4" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="app_name" type="SOME_COMPLEX_TYPE_WITH_ENUM_1_AS_NAME" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />     
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

but in sequence there cannot appear two elements with same name (I cannot change this name).

So is there any way, to achive this in xs:schema version="1.0"

adding some example xml:

1. validation passed: (OK)

   ```
     <Metadata>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_1" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_2" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_3" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_4" Value="some_value"/>
       </Metadata>
   ```
2. validation passed: (OK)

   ```
       <Metadata>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_1" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_1" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_3" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_4" Value="some_value"/>
       </Metadata>
   ```
3. validation passed: (OK) its ok, enum_1 and enum_3 (which for me are required) and at least 4 app_name -> validation pass

   ```
       <Metadata>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_1" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_1" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_3" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_3" Value="some_value"/>
       </Metadata>
   ```
4. validation passed: (NOT OK - missing enum_1 which I want to be required, but right now validation is pass - xsd check only count of app_name occurs)

   ```
     <Metadata>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_2" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_2" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_3" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_3" Value="some_value"/>
       <app_name ERE="some_ere" Name="enum_4" Value="some_value"/>
       </Metadata>
   ```

Shortly (response to comment):

I want to have xsd validation which check if in xml document exists elements:

```
<metadata>
<ERE ..... name="enum_1".../> 
<ERE ..... name="enum_3".../>
</metadata>
```

if those element not exists, then validation should fail.

Comment: Your verbal description is difficult to follow.  I suggest that you show some examples of what you would like to be valid XML and some examples of what you'd like to be invalid XML.

Comment: Also, please read [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and review how you're asking questions and [**accepting**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) answers.   *0 accepts out of 14 questions asked looks amiss.*

Comment: @kjhughes Thanks for guide. I added xml example.

Comment: You're using enumerations for a purpose for which they were never intended. If you try to focus on describing what you are trying to achieve, rather than on your difficulties achieving your goals using the wrong tool for the job, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: @MichaelKay so what is correct tool for the job? Enumeration in this case not working - I'm already know that. I'm starting with enumeration, because in earlier implementation it was working fine (when checking if exists in xml specific value of enum was not need), so this is my starting point to force checking concrete value of enum in given xml.

Comment: Tell us what the job is. You haven't explained it.

Comment: @MichaelKay explanation added. I hope its clear?